# Sending file input doesn't work

Tags: html, forms

I want to send a file by a form, but I don't undersand why, after the post the data of file is always empty.

All others data that I sent inside form, I haven't problem, just if I want to send a file.

An idea ?

```
<form name="contact" action="mysite.com/boutique/index.php?Info&Contact&Process&action=process" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="d190f7c98c1f66b7147e0d239a1e23ce" />

    <div class="controls col-md-6">
      <input type="file" name="evidence_document" id="file" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary">Continuer</button>
</form>
```

an example about my test: like you can see evidence_document doesn't exist !

```
array(9) { 
["formid"]=> string(32) "d190f7c98c1f66b7147e0d239a1e23ce" 
["name"]=> string(13) "test"
["email"]=> string(30) "test@testt.com" 
["customers_telephone"]=> string(14) "09 88 55 44 55"
["customer_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["order_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
["email_subject"]=> string(14) "fdgdsfgdsfgsdf" 
["enquiry"]=> string(23) "gdgsdfgdsfgsdfgfdsgfdsg" ["number_email_confirmation"]=> string(1) "5"
 }
```

Addition information

```
     object(ClicShopping\OM\Upload)#38 (8) { 
["_file":protected]=> string(17) "evidence_document" 
["_filename":protected]=> NULL 
["_destination":protected]=> string(61) "/var/www//boutique/sources/download/Evidence" 
["_permissions":protected]=> int(511) 
["_extensions":protected]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> string(3) "mp4" 
[1]=> string(3) "jpg" } 
["_replace":protected]=> string(9) "201610_2_" 
["_upload":protected]=> array(0) { } 
["_maxsize"]=> NULL } NULL
```

Comment: Can you show what you are doing on the receiving side to confirm that the file is not being transmitted?

Comment: Can you add a new input which type is text.

Comment: The example is a summary of the form, this is only this field does not work. It's just <input type="file" ....>.
All the other texarea, text ... works fine.
If I write <?php echo $_post['name'], I have the result. but not on evidence_document

Comment: Added more information in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not find the file on the post array. They are coming with the $_FILES array.

```
$_FILES['evidence_document']; // your file is here
```

not on;

```
$_POST['evidence_document'];
```